# Pushdown Automata for Palindrones

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language, pushdown-automaton

So I've found this PDA to accept palindromes in the language {0,1}*.

[image: Palindrone PDA]

However, I'm failing to understand how it could could accept '1' or '0'.

In `B` it can read a 1 or 0 and push the same symbol to the stack and then go to `C`. However once it's in `C`, it has nowhere to go as to reach $ in the stack another symbol needs to be read.

Can someone explain how it works?

I'm thinking that in order to accept a single symbol, we would need a transition from `B` to `D` => `1,$->ε | 0,$->ε`.

Would I be correct?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right. This PDA will not accept 0 or 1 (or, more generally, any odd-length palindrome - do you see why?)

To fix this, I'd recommend adding these transitions from B to C:

> 0, ε → ε
>
> 1, ε → ε

These transitions essentially let you consume a character "for free." If you pick the middle character and the string is a palindrome, great! Then you'll accept. If you pick the wrong character or the string isn't a palindrome, you'll never make it through states C and D without the automaton dying.

Comment: I think the suggestion I added in my edit is equivalent to your suggestion.

Comment: @mickzer I'm not sure it is, actually. Try the string 111 with your edit and with mine.

Comment: But with that change, it would suddenly accept a non-palindrome such as `01`.

Comment: Can you give the sequence of transitions that would result in 01 being accepted? I’m not seeing how to do that with the revised automaton but am happy to be corrected. :-)

Comment: I would, but I am incorrect!  Sorry about that :)  I confuse myself sometimes LOL